# How can I grab and use path from STDOUT in Python 2.7 (OS X)

Tags: python, applescript, subprocess

This question is related to those using OS X because I am returning a path from the foremost Finder window using an AppleScript. I want to get this path and list the directory contents. Ultimately I will use the output to rename files.

For some reason the code below yields `OSError: 2, 'No such file or directory'`

Here is the code:

```
import os

from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT,call 

def ascript():
    cmd = """osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to get the quoted form of the POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias) '"""
    proc=Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, ) 
    output,err=proc.communicate()
    return output.rstrip()

stuff = os.listdir(ascript())
```

I have also tried:

```
path = ascript()
stuff = os.listdir(path)
```

Comment: try running: python absolute_path/file.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return a quoted form of the POSIX path. When you do that, python is literally reading:

```
'/path/to/window'
```

When you remove the `quoted form` it returns the correct path format:

```
/path/to/window
```

Comment: You need the path to be quoted if there are spaces in the path. That also does not solve the problem.

Comment: I tested it using a directory with a space and it worked fine for me. Is it not working correctly for you?

Comment: You tested my script in its entirety? If I do something simple like select the Pictures folder in Finder window 1 and run the script, it should pass ~/Pictures to the python variable `output` and ultimately to `stuff`. I put in a `print stuff` to verify this and it successfully prints the path, however, os.listdir(stuff) gives me `OSError: 2, 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: @macmadness86 I've [Created a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48962/room-for-darrick-herwehe-and-macmadness86) to discuss this further.

Comment: It was working. For some reason I deleted the `.rstrip()` method, which is essential to the code. I put it back and got rid of `the quoted form of` and it worked! You were right! Thanks